# Error about using pl2303 with raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, usbserial

I want to use uart to debug the raspberry Pi.

Firstly, I using the Ubuntu20.04(virtual environment) to check the performance of TTL convert usb.

When I prepare the raspberry Pi OS, and config the uart in it like this

```
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
force_turbo=1
```

the `dmesg` command list this:

```
[   37.829727] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[   37.829775] pl2303 2-2.2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[   37.849832] usb 2-2.2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

But when I use minicom, there is nothing print to screen, and then I use `dmesg` command.
It prints this:

```
[ 2385.413344] pl2303 2-2.2:1.0: pl2303_vendor_write - failed to write [0008]: -110
[ 2386.072005] pl2303 2-2.2:1.0: pl2303_vendor_write - failed to write [0009]: -110
[ 2386.414264] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_get_line_request - failed: -110
[ 2387.072914] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_set_line_request - failed: -110
[ 2387.415171] pl2303 2-2.2:1.0: pl2303_vendor_read - failed to read [0080]: -110
[ 2388.073664] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_set_control_lines - failed: -110
```

I have no idea about it.